# Student Canadian visa application

Tags: visa, canada

I'm applying for a student visa and my father is paying for my expenses. He has all the money available but he usually doesn't keep his money in one bank. Now that I have to provide a bank statement with all the amount in one bank, and it has to be there for not less than 3 months, is this going to be a problem? Because he can gather all of the money and put it in one bank for a statement, but it won't be there for 3 months before I apply for the visa. My program starts soon.

Comment: Where is a requirement to have all monies in one bank stated?

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to move money around for the purpose of a visa application because you will then have to explain why you moved it, in addition to the normal process of proving the funds are yours and are from legitimate sources.

Comment: I would provide all of the bank statements from the separate banks and show the arithmetic proving that the sum exists. But I would also get a letter from your father stating that this is his money from his job as a [Whatever]. I'd also provide more than 3 months if possible.

Comment: u can give statements for multiple accounts in different banks